# Assistance In Query Logic and Order of Operations

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly new to MySQL and was having some difficulty understanding why the following query is working as it does:

```
select user, COUNT(*) c FROM user_rows GROUP BY user HAVING c > 1 ORDER BY c;
```

Now, the output is correct: it lists a user along with how many rows they have in the user_rows table.

My question is why doesn't the COUNT(*) just return the number of rows in the user_rows table? Is it an Order of Operations thing? Just trying to get added clarity for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you have a `group by` clause then all aggregate functions like `count` or `sum` are applied to each group and not the complete data in the table.

Since you group by the `user`, the count is calculated for each user.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't count all rows in the table is because you are grouping by user

Answer (score 1):

Your GROUP BY clause is affecting the behavior of the COUNT statement, as you have noted. GROUP BY directly affects the results returned by making each row an aggregate of all rows matching the group by clause. That's why COUNT ( and SUM, if you use it ) will be specific to each value GROUPed by.